# How to create a transparent background using headless Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

I have a [svg](https://dhappy.org/.../image/heart/svg.svg) that uses CSS to animate the colors. I would like to take that image and convert it to an emoji, but I am having difficulty generating a transparent background. I have a [simple script](https://github.com/dysbulic/rasterize) that looks like:

```js
await client.Emulation.setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride({
  color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0 }
})
await Page.startScreencast({ format: 'png', everyNthFrame: 1 });
let counter = 1
while(counter <= iters) {
  const { data, metadata, sessionId } = (
    await Page.screencastFrame()
  )
  const out = `shot.${(counter++).toString().padStart(2, '0')}.png`
  fs.writeFileSync(
    out, Buffer.from(data, 'base64')
  )
  await Page.screencastFrameAck({ sessionId })
}
```

The background comes out as opaque black.

Comment: You're right. I started the question, fixed the problem the question was about, then asked another.

Comment: I suspect that a transparent background is incompatible with a screencast. I posted [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1178996#makechanges) on crbugs.org.